# Windows 10: Move and convert partition

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid

I have the following problem:

On a Windows 10 System with a Adaptec Raid Controller, I have a logical dynamic disk (disk 1) and i plugged in a JBOD (disk 2).

Disk 1 was originally the size of 2TB, but was then replaced step by step with 2x6TB, giving 6TB of Raid1 Storage. The JBOD is empty and has 2TB.

Disk 1 contains two partitions, "Data" and "Software", but they are not in one piece, since they were enlarged multiple times, but only in small increments. So now a lot of little partition items of the two partitions can be seen in the view. This gives problem by further expanding the disk to 6TB (in Windows).

My target is the following:

- Copy the contents to the JBOD, erase Disk1, create freshly partitions (4TB and 2TB)
- Restore data

For the data partition, i just used `xcopy` to copy all the files to the new JBOD, and then removed partition "Data".

But since "Software" contains installation of programs, it is not possible to copy the data to JBOD. Also, common imaging tools, such as Acronis, are no use here, since they backup the complete partition (including all the fragments), so a restore would result in the same problem.

Is there any way, to merge all the little partition fragments, or a similar solution? My goal is to 1:1 copy all data from "Software" to another location, and then re-copy to the freshly created raid volume. Basically create an "Image" without the partition information.

Edit:
Here is a screnshot of "Disk1". Data D: copied to G:, D: will be removed. P: will be deleted. I: should be copied to another disk (Disk4) and then should be recast to new volume created on Disk 1 (new full 6TB instead of 4095GB)

Image of Partition:

[image: Image of Partition]

Comment: It would be clearer if you posted a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: I have added the screenshot now

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this is by capturing a WIM, or WIMs, of the partitions, then applying the WIM(s) after re-arranging the partition layout.

- There's a few ways to do this, but the partitions with installed programs are going to present an issue if these are not portable installs or saved to linked junction points *(i.e. sane directory linking to directories the OS expects software to be installed to, which are the `%ProgramFiles%` folders or `%AppData%`)*.

  - Whenever software is installed on Windows, it generally has data saved elsewhere vital to the software *(registry entries, potential data saved in `%ProgramData%`, etc.)*
  - Provided all registry entries for each application installed are easy to find and aren't saved under arbitrarily generated GUIDs, a program like [RegEditX](https://www.dcsoft.com/products/regeditx/)'s RegCrawler can find and bulk replace volume or partition paths, but it's likely certain aspects of some, if not many, of the installed software will be broken *(uninstallers for instance or broken entries in CP's Installed Program's list, etc.)* when applying the data to a partition with a different drive letter or mount point.

---

### Imaging

When it comes to Windows, 3rd party tools are *not* an efficient way to image a partition, as Windows natively supports imaging of partitions via **[`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)** in Windows >=8, or [**`ImageX`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) in Windows <=7, of which are far superior to 3rd party cloning tools and do not cause configuration issues.

- Windows has *always* natively supported imaging of partitions or individual directories.

  - *The system partition can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE, while all other partitions are able to be imaged while booted to Windows.*
  - WIM *(**W**indows **IM**age)* files can be captured of an entire partition or individual folders/files. 
     Create a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file to specify exclusions or exceptions.
- All WinPE/WinRE  [WIMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) have either `ImageX` or `DISM` included within them.

  - **WinPE:** ***Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment*

    - *Such as a Windows Setup boot media (**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
  - **WinRE:** ***Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment*

    - *WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra [WinPE Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery*

---

#### Commands

*WinPE only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default, so `/ScratchDir` is required*

- **Windows >=8: [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14)** is utilized

  - Capture an image:

    ```powershell
    DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2019.10.10 @ 08:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Append an image:

    ```powershell
    DISM /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2019.10.10 @ 08:30" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Apply an image:

    ```powershell
    DISM /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.esd" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
- **Windows <=7: [`ImageX`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx)** is utilized in lieu of `DISM`:

  - Capture an image:

    ```powershell
    ImageX /Capture "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2019.10.10 @ 08:30" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Append an image:

    ```powershell
    ImageX /Append "C:" "Z:\Base.esd" "Windows Backup" "Base Image 2019.10.10 @ 08:30" /Compress:Recovery /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```
  - Apply an image:

    ```powershell
    ImageX /Apply "Z:\Base.wim" 1 "C:" /Check /Verify /NoRpFix /ScratchDir:"Z:\"
    ```

---

#### NOTE:

- **It's *impossible* for an ESD/WIM image to become corrupted**

  - Provided imaging commands are *always* issued with:

    - **DISM:** `/CheckIntegrity` & `/Verify`
    - **ImageX:** `/Check` & `/Verify`
- **ESDs can only be taken of a *system* partition**

  - `/Compress:Recovery` is the only compression algorithm available.

    - ESD compression ratio is ~33% more efficient than the WIM compression ratio.
    - *In Windows 10, Microsoft only allows ESDs for Push-Button Reset exported images*
- **ESDs/WIMs are smart compression image formats**

  - Only changed files are added to an image when a new image is appended to it

    - Newly appended images utilize the same copy of unchanged files already contained within the image from the previous image(s).

      - This allows for an image to remain small in relation to the data contained within.

---

#### DISM & ImageX Prerequisites

- **Easy**

  1. Download & create a [bootable USB](https://rufus.ie/):

     - **DISM:** [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
     - **ImageX:** [Windows 7 Install ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7)
  2. Once booted from it, press: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** to open a terminal
  3. [DISM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) / [ImageX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749447(v=ws.10).aspx) commands

     - [Capture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image) or [Append](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image) an Image
     - [Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image)

       - Get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo) *(`ImageX /Info`)*, prior to applying, ensuring correct index [image] is being applied.
- **Custom:** *Create a WinPE/RE image*

  1. **Install:**

     - Windows ADK *(8 & 10)* || AIK *(7)* is specific to the version of Windows installed.

       1. **ADK:**

          - For Windows >=10 v1809: [WinPE Addon for ADK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2087112)
          - For Windows <=10 v1803: [Windows ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install)

            - **Select:** *Windows PE* & *Deployment Tools*
       2. **AIK:**

          - ImageX: [Windows 7 AIK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753)

            - **Run:** `StartCD.exe` > *Windows AIK Setup*
  2. **Create:**

     - [Microsoft WinPE Wiki](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive)

       - [Customize WinPE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-mount-and-customize)
       - [Customize WinRE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/dn898523.aspx)
     - [Reboot.Pro Wiki](http://reboot.pro/topic/19156-create-a-bootable-winpe-50-x64-usb-drive/)
  3. **Boot it**

---

### Example: `/Get-WIMinfo` || `/Info`

```powershell
PS $  ls -file

  Directory: Z:\WIM

    Mode                LastWriteTime            Length  Name
    ----                -------------            ------  ----
    -a----        2018.12.24 03:34:13   95,019,530,773B  Base.wim
    -a----        2016.06.14 22:32:36              568B  DISM.cmd
    -a----        2016.05.17 05:36:10               97B  wimscript.ini

PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

    Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes

    Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes

    Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes

    Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes

    Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes

    Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes

  The operation completed successfully.
```

```powershell
PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:1

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 1
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Base (Drivers Only)
      Size : 22,710,283,446 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 24288
      Files : 112665
      Created : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Modified : 2018.05.05 - 13:56:47
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:2

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 2
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (No Customizations)
      Size : 45,591,850,754 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 1
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 45803
      Files : 203058
      Created : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:47
      Modified : 2018.05.06 - 01:55:48
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:3

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 3
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Installed (Customized)
      Size : 94,958,267,312 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 62409
      Files : 350446
      Created : 2018.06.01 - 19:09:51
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:4

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 4
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 1 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,588,267,910 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 61908
      Files : 346074
      Created : 2018.06.08 - 21:54:02
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:5

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 5
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1803: Software Group 2 Installed (Customized)
      Size : 101,905,314,237 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17134
      ServicePack Build : 1
      ServicePack Level : 81
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 76113
      Files : 423408
      Created : 2018.06.09 - 20:38:36
      Modified : 2018.06.19 - 21:26:18
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.


PS $  dism /get-wiminfo /wimfile:Base.wim /index:6

  Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
  Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Details for image : Base.wim

      Index : 6
      Name : Alienware 18: Windows 10
      Description : v1809: Updated Applications
      Size : 114,959,954,040 bytes
      WIM Bootable : No
      Architecture : x64
      Hal : acpiapic
      Version : 10.0.17763
      ServicePack Build : 195
      ServicePack Level : 0
      Edition : Professional
      Installation : Client
      ProductType : WinNT
      ProductSuite : Terminal Server
      System Root : WINDOWS
      Directories : 87659
      Files : 452028
      Created : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:13
      Modified : 2018.12.24 - 04:27:15
      Languages :
              en-US (Default)

  The operation completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks maybe too simple to be true.
There is no problem taking a backup of a partition, then returning it to a larger one.

To start with, if Windows is entirely installed on C, then all you need is to boot
in Safe mode to be able to copy the contents of the partitions on Disk 1,
and you don't need to follow the rest of my answer.

One tool that can help for example is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).
It can backup to a file archive an entire partition, and it backups only the used
sectors, then return it to a partition of a different size.

The sequence of events should be:

- Ensure that Windows is entirely installed on C and does not use Disk 1
  (no page-file etc)
- Install AOMEI Backupper to C
- Backup the partitions using AOMEI (but also using another method, just in case)
- Boot in Safe mode to avoid third-party products running from D
- Delete the partitions and re-partition Disk 1
- Restore the contents of the partitions using AOMEI